# PDT XDebug. How to debug with ip address but not localhost

Tags: php, debugging, xampp, xdebug

I am developing a PHP project and using PDT with XDebug which is working smoothly at `localhost`. (By the way, I am using XAMPP in windows 7)

Now, I want to debug some of the features from other PCs which need to use my local IP(or pc name) for request.

But I even can not debug at my local PC with IP address that is like `http://127.0.0.1/xxx` or `http://192.168.1.yyy/xxx`.

I have looked up some articles which introduced to change some settings in the `php.ini` and httpd.conf files. But there is no help to me (I have done some of them at the begining of I setting up the project and without problem to use localhost).

Comment: I tried to move my environment to WinXP, and finally could debug the project by IP address at WinXP (but not yet Win7). The problem is that I can only debug in IE (but not yet FF/Safari/Chrome) and cannot debug from other PCs' IE yet... What the hell with it? Help me, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is that first launch one browser (`ie`, `ff`, `safari`, etc.), 
and enter the `url` I want to debug(of course there is no any response at this time)
Then I add `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP` just behind the url.
Secondly I launch another browser and enter the url I want to debug again,
but this time, you will have the PDT been going into debug mode.

Soruce: http://devzone.zend.com/1147/debugging-php-applications-with-xdebug/
by searching `XDEBUG_SESSION_START` which gave me the hint.